# Is there a limit to how high you can go in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a limit to how high you can go?

Well I got to something like 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 (I think) but I don't know as it went of the screen. Also it says 'Outside of world...' at the bottom left of the debugging menu. When you are this high when you fly up or down it does not change it!
Please watch this video:

. 
Yes I did have to edit the photo but from the video you can see that the picture is still displaying the same number. [image]